# Exporting target from a Build Tree with namespace in CMake

Tags: cmake

I export my library in its CMakeLists.txt:

```
export(TARGETS TARGET_NAME NAMESPACE mynamespace:: FILE "TARGET_NAME.cmake")
```

and in my main CMakeLists.txt I link my project with it:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mynamespace::TARGET_NAME)
```

when I run cmake I get this error:

```
the target was not found.
```

but without namespace it works.

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} TARGET_NAME)
```

how to make it works with namespace too?

Comment: You seems misunderstand intention of `export()` command. It is indended to build the library project **separately** from the main one. That is, main project do NOT include the library project with `add_subdirectory`. But main project may use `find_package()` for include the library target from the library project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I read more about it and I think you are right.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I understand the NAMESPACE argument sets up import rules, but: 
While it's unnecessary, as most would reasonably assume that a target_link_libraries() call with just the name of target that does not have a namespace is likely referring to a target within the build tree, **is there a way to configure the target so that the syntax the OP attempted works?** So that you can refer to a non-imported target via its eventual namespace for extra clarity (in cases where the target's component names overlap with those of an imported target, so a cursory glance *may* lead to confusion)?

Comment: @oblivioncth: For non-imported target you could create an ALIAS target (`add_library(ALIAS)`) with the same name, as NAMESPACE gives for the imported target.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Excellent, seems to work fine for this use case.